# Handle null stream in video tag

Tags: c#, jquery, html, wcf

I have the following html code :

```
<video width="426" height="240" controls="" preload="auto" autoplay="">
    <source src="http://localhost:8081/VideoStream">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video
</video>
```

In the C# server part i have the following code :

```
public Stream VideoStream()
{
   try
   {
         return File.OpenRead(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "video.ogg"));
   }catch(Exception)
   {
     return Stream.Null;
   }
}
```

The code is working, but i would like to know somehow in html that i received that `Stream.Null` so that i can display an error message instead of a video player that is not rendering anything.

Can you give me some hints how can i achieve this ?

Comment: i would like to know in html that i received a null stream .

Answer (score 0):

As `Stream.Null` just returns a new `NullStream` which is a valid stream with the length of 0 bites you can only check if the stream is empty.

In javascript you could check if the [`duration`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_duration.asp) value of the video tag is equals `0`. You can do this in the [`loadedmetadata`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadedmetadata.asp) event.

```
<script>
    var video = $('<video width="426" height="240" controls="" preload="auto" autoplay="">' + 
                      '<source src="http://localhost:8081/VideoStream">' +
                      'Your browser does not support HTML5 video' +
                  '</video>');

    video.on('loadedmetadata', function(evt) {
        if(evt.target.duration === 0) {
            console.log("The video is empty");
        } else {
            console.log("The video has content");
        }
    });
    video.on('error', function(evt) {
        console.log("The video cannot be played");
    });

    $(document.body).append(video);
</script>
```

> The loadedmetadata event occurs when meta data for the specified video has been loaded. Meta data for video consists of: duration, dimensions and text tracks.

Comment: For some reason the event won't fire. my video element is dinamically added, so i used the following code :$(document).on('loadedmetadata', 'video', function (evt)

Comment: @Lucian This won't work. Like this you register the `loadedmetadata` event on the `document`. You need to do it like I described in the answer. Also if you dynamicly add your video

Comment: same. won't fire. if i change loadedmetadata with click it will work

Comment: @Lucian I've edited my answer to show how it could work with a dynamicly added video. Note that the event is registered before the element is added to the html.

Comment: @Lucian If you use the click event you allways have to `click` to trigger the behavior. With the `loadedmetadata` event it will happen automaticly

Comment: This event still won't fire on my machine for a Stream.Null. For a valid Stream it will fire

Comment: @Lucian does the `video.on('error', function(evt) {` event fire for the empty video?

Comment: no, it is not fired . Only the loadstart event is fired

Comment: @Lucian and the `onloadstart` event? If the `readyState` of the video is allready `1` or higher you could ignore the event and just do the duration check.

Comment: ready state is 0 in both cases (Stream.Null or valid Stream) ; and duration (also in both cases) is NaN

Comment: @Lucian are you sure that the `preload` attribute is set to `auto` or `metadata`? It seems like the video is not loading.

Comment: with preload="metadata" it iwll fire only for a valid stream . In the past few hours i've change in logic in the backend so that i can provide a valid stream in any situation . Thank you for your help .